# Node JS Memory Leak?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node app (v0.8.26) running on Express (v3.4.8). In that app I have a route that sends an array of objects in the response body. What I'm finding is that doing so immediately begins spinning up the Node memory usage and before long everything shuts down. I'm getting a little desperate so I'm hoping someone can help (quickly).

Here's my route:

```
get_products: function(req, res) {
  var san = req.params.san;

  // Authenticate and then retrieve
  client.login(datasources.api.auth.sourceId, datasources.api.auth.password, function(err, authToken) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(401, err);
    }

    client.getProducts(token, san, function(err, products) {
      if (err) {
        var httpStatus = err.httpStatus || 500;

        if (httpStatus === 500) {
          console.trace(err);
        }

        return res.send(httpStatus, err.message);
      }

      if (products) {
        return products.length > 0
          ? res.send(200, products)  // <--- ERROR OCCURS HERE
          : res.send(200, []);
      }
      else {
        return res.send(403, 'Purchase is not allowed at this time.');
      }
    });
  });
},
```

And the array being returned looks like this:

```
[ { PRODUCTID: '7',
    PRODUCTNAME: 'Token 1',
    QTY: '500',
    PRICE: '5',
    AVAILABLE: '1',
    PRODUCTTYPE: '1',
    BILLINGDEALNAME: 'Token 1' },
  { PRODUCTID: '8',
    PRODUCTNAME: 'Token 2',
    QTY: '1000',
    PRICE: '9',
    AVAILABLE: '1',
    PRODUCTTYPE: '1',
    BILLINGDEALNAME: 'Token 2' },
  { PRODUCTID: '9',
    PRODUCTNAME: 'Token 3',
    QTY: '2000',
    PRICE: '16',
    AVAILABLE: '1',
    PRODUCTTYPE: '1',
    BILLINGDEALNAME: 'Token 3' },
  { PRODUCTID: '5',
    PRODUCTNAME: 'Token - Free',
    QTY: '500',
    PRICE: '0',
    AVAILABLE: '0',
    PRODUCTTYPE: '0',
    BILLINGDEALNAME: 'Token - Free Token Use' },
  { PRODUCTID: '6',
    PRODUCTNAME: 'Token - Prepaid',
    QTY: '500',
    PRICE: '0',
    AVAILABLE: '0',
    PRODUCTTYPE: '0',
    BILLINGDEALNAME: 'Token - Prepaid Token Use' } ]
```

I know it's not a ton of information, but it's all I have. If I force the route to return an empty array in the response, there's no problem. I don't know where else to look.

Help?!

**UPDATE**

I've tweaked the code slightly for debugging. The ternary operator has been ditched:

```
if (products.length > 0) {
  //return res.send(200, []);
  console.error('RETURNING PRODUCTS');
  console.error(products);
  // return res.send(200, []);

  return res.send(200, products);
}
else {
  return res.send(200, []);
}
```

Comment: can you try `res.json(200,products);return;` ?

Comment: Trying it now, but I can't come up with a reason this would behave any differently. What are you thinking it might do?

Comment: well instead of returning a method `res.send` you should better call the method and use `return` to terminate, sometimes in asyncronous calls it will keep executing the code inside a callback.. i thing that might be the problem here.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Weird that sending an empty array in the response body works, but a populated array fails. Also, there isn't really any other code to execute in the method.

Comment: No luck. Watching the node memory rise...

Comment: whats the length of array? and what does express logger outputs?

Comment: The array is exactly what you see. 5 relatively small objects. No errors in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this, for my specific problem, at least, was to downgrade [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) from 3.4.x to 3.3.x. Because this is a production system, I wasn't able to play with it in order to gain a more sophisticated understanding of what was happening and I've never been able to reproduce this in my downstream environments.

Just wanted to close this out for anyone who may be searching later.

Answer (score 0):

try recent version of nodejs - 0.10.26 - i have similiar issues in nodejs of 0.8.x versions

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that. I have to connect to an API over TLS. Node v0.10.26 uses a newer version of TLS that the API server can't negotiate.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can use streaming in response

```
if (products.length > 0) {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  products.map(res.write);
  res.end();
}
else {
  return res.send(200, []);
}
```